# 1 Button 3 Command onclick android

Tags: android

How to include 3 Commands into one button?
I want insert open another activity, when button click.

This my code:

```
btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG, "submit clicked");
    if (!Ultils.isConnectingToInternet(SubmitPropertiesActivity.this)) {
       showMsg(getResources().getString(R.string.open_network));
    } else {
       doUpload();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Whats the issue here?

Comment: I want , after this button run to check connection and do upload , and i want insert open another activity after upload .

Comment: If you are looking to start a new activity after successful upload, you need to share your code for doUpload()

Comment: yes ,, this is my code .

Answer (score 0):

Just add line in `onClick` method

`startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),anotherActivity.class));`

like
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "submit clicked");
        //other command
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),anotherActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add start activity code in runOnUiThread after dismiss dialog and clear all data then add your start activity code.

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    prgDialog.dismiss();
                                    title.setText("");
                                    price.setText("");
                                    content.setText("");
                                    address.setText("");
                                    area.setText("");
                                    lantai.setText("");
                                    luasbangunan.setText("");
                                    bathroom.setText("");
                                    bedroom.setText("");
                                    selected_amenities_list.clear();
                                    marker_selected = 0;

                                  //Here You add your start new activity code.

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help you;

Write 3 Methods

1) Network check method

2) Upload image method

3) Start an Activity method

When the button is click;

Call Method (1)

if Network connection is there - then

Call Method (2) from Method (1)

Check if uploading method finishs, if it does -

Call Method (3) from there

This is a simple procedure, just giving you the idea I would use If I'm in the situation.